shared legend position is not changed
\documentclass{article}
% Standard package includes
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}

% For proper rendering and hyphenation of words containing Latin characters (including in bib files)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% For Vietnamese characters
% \usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
% See https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf for other character sets

% This assumes your files are encoded as UTF8
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% This is not strictly necessary and may be commented out.
% However, it will improve the layout of the manuscript,
% and will typically save some space.
\usepackage{microtype}

% This is also not strictly necessary and may be commented out.
% However, it will improve the aesthetics of text in
% the typewriter font.
\usepackage{inconsolata}

% dot line
\usepackage{arydshln}

\setlength{\dashlinedash}{0.2pt}
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.3pt}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabularx}


% multirow
\usepackage{multirow}

% table color
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\def\thickhline{\noalign{\hrule height.8pt}}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{amaranth}{rgb}{0.9, 0.17, 0.31}
\definecolor{americanrose}{rgb}{1.0, 0.01, 0.24}
\definecolor{lightskyblue}{rgb}{0.53, 0.81, 0.98}
\definecolor{limegreen}{rgb}{0.2, 0.8, 0.2}
\definecolor{mossgreen}{rgb}{0.68, 0.87, 0.68}
\definecolor{babyblueeyes}{rgb}{0.63, 0.79, 0.95}
\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
\definecolor{columbiablue}{rgb}{0.61, 0.87, 1.0}
\definecolor{brightlavender}{rgb}{0.75, 0.58, 0.89}
\definecolor{brightube}{rgb}{0.82, 0.62, 0.91}
\definecolor{brilliantlavender}{rgb}{0.96, 0.73, 1.0}
\definecolor{beige}{rgb}{0.96, 0.96, 0.86}
\definecolor{bananamania}{rgb}{0.98, 0.91, 0.71}
\definecolor{apricot}{rgb}{0.98, 0.81, 0.69}

% graphic
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

% math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% tikz
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={GLUE avg.},
            xlabel={params.},
            width=0.45\textwidth,
            xminorticks=true,
            xmode=log,
            extra x ticks={100000000},
            ytick align=outside,
            xtick align=outside,
            ytick={60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85},
            xtick pos=left,
            ytick pos=left,
            tickwidth=2pt,
            grid,
            grid style=dotted,
            ]
            \addplot[color=amaranth!80!black, mark=*] coordinates {(220234752,85.4)};
            \addplot[color=brightube!80!black, mark=otimes*] coordinates {(1779456,82.3)};
            \addplot[color=limegreen!80!black, mark=triangle*] coordinates {(624784,77.6)};
            \addplot[color=apricot!80!black, mark=square*] coordinates {(7680,60.4)};
            \addplot[color=lightskyblue!80!black, mark=diamond*] coordinates {(2304,73.3)};
            \addplot[color=blue!80!white, mark=diamond*] coordinates {(2304,80.5)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={SuperGLUE avg.},
            xlabel={params.},
            width=0.45\textwidth,
            xminorticks=true,
            xmode=log,
            extra x ticks={100000000},
            ytick align=outside,
            xtick align=outside,
            ytick={55, 60, 65, 70, 75},
            xtick pos=left,
            ytick pos=left,
            tickwidth=2pt,
            grid,
            grid style=dotted,
            tickwidth=1pt,
            legend image post style={only marks},
            legend to name=sharedLegend,
            ]
            \addplot[color=amaranth!80!black, mark=*] coordinates {(220234752,76.0)};\addlegendentry{Fine-tuning};
            \addplot[color=brightube!80!black, mark=otimes*] coordinates {(1779456,74.6)};\addlegendentry{P-T};
            \addplot[color=limegreen!80!black, mark=triangle*] coordinates {(624784,66.6)};\addlegendentry{RPT};
            \addplot[color=apricot!80!black, mark=square*] coordinates {(7680,57.4)};\addlegendentry{PT};
            \addplot[color=lightskyblue!80!black, mark=diamond*] coordinates {(2304,67.8)};\addlegendentry{EPT};
            \addplot[color=blue!80!white, mark=diamond*] coordinates {(2304,72.1)};\addlegendentry{EPT*};
            \legend{Fine-tuning,P-T,RPT,PT,EPT,EPT*}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    {\scalefont{0.65}
        \pgfplotslegendfromname{sharedLegend}
    }
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:enter-labels}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



The legend position remains aligned at the bottom even after repeatedly changing the location. How can I align the shared legend at the top as shown below?


\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
    legend style={matrix anchor=north west, at={(0pt,0pt)}},
    every legend to name picture/.style={baseline},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[anchor=north west, at={(0pt,0pt)}]
\addplot[blue, mark=*] coordinates {(220234752,85.4)};
\addplot[red, mark=otimes*] coordinates {(1779456,82.3)};
\addplot[green, mark=triangle*] coordinates {(624784,77.6)};
\addplot[cyan, mark=square*] coordinates {(7680,60.4)};
\addplot[teal, mark=diamond*] coordinates {(2304,73.3)};
\addplot[orange, mark=diamond*] coordinates {(2304,80.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
anchor=north west, at={(0pt,0pt)},
legend image post style={only marks},
legend to name=sharedLegend,
]
\addplot[blue, mark=*] coordinates {(220234752,76.0)};\addlegendentry{Fine-tuning};
\addplot[pink, mark=otimes*] coordinates {(1779456,74.6)};\addlegendentry{P-T};
\addplot[teal, mark=triangle*] coordinates {(624784,66.6)};\addlegendentry{RPT};
\addplot[violet, mark=square*] coordinates {(7680,57.4)};\addlegendentry{PT};
\addplot[gray, mark=diamond*] coordinates {(2304,67.8)};\addlegendentry{EPT};
\addplot[blue, mark=diamond*] coordinates {(2304,72.1)};\addlegendentry{EPT*};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotslegendfromname{sharedLegend}
\end{document}


